# Connect SSD1306 OLED Display to BLE Nano

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, microcontroller

My experience with micocontrollers and electronics is limited to ATmega Controllers, programmed in C and some tranistors and displays, nothing too special.

However, I want to get my hardware one step smaller, and want to start using the BLE Nano for all Bluetooth related projects.
For a first example project I'd like to create a bluetooth enabled temperature sensor with a small display.

As Display I chose the 0.96" OLED Display from Adafruit, which features a SSD1306 Controller. Adafruit offers a library for it (here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306 ) but it is not clear to me, if I can use this library together with the BLE Nano.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I was to fixated on using the arduino library for my "normal" project.
There are other libraries out there, for example on github, which are written in plain c and should therefore be easier tot adapt for different platforms.

Comment: For further reference and anyone else who is looking for a library to use the SSD1306 Displays, I found the following:

https://github.com/tibounise/SSD1306-AVR

I did not do much with it, but it seems to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

The Adafruit library is an Arduino library, so you would need to register your BLE Nano module in order to gain access to Red Bear's pre-release Arduino library - See the "Using Arduino" section of the ["Getting Started with nRF51822"](http://redbearlab.com/getting-started-nrf51822/) page

Comment: I intended to do it the other way round: I do NOT want to use Arduino, or the Arduino IDE but stick to ATmels AVR Studio.
But I want to use the Library written for the SSD1306 chip

Comment: Then you would need to "reverse engineer" that library and adapt the code.  In theory the C should be reasonably portable, but you would need to adapt the SPI routines.  The library also depends on the Adafruit graphics library, so you would need to port that too.